# Storing form data into wordpress database

Tags: customization

How can i create a input form in my existing wordpress website and store the data into database. I am using free swift theme.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a shortcode to add inside a page, then create the form template by code and show it on the page.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple code to add a form in a page:

```
add_shortcode( 'myform', 'add_myform' );
function add_myform( $atts ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['myname'] ) ) {
        $myname  = $_POST['myname'];
        update_option( 'myname', $myname );
    } else {
        $myname = get_option( 'myname' );
    }

    $myform = "<form method='post' action=''>";
    $myform .= "<input type='text' name='myname' value='" . $myname . "'>";
    $myform .= "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
    $myform .= "</form>";
    return $myform;
}
```

Add the shortcode `[myform]` in a page and the form will be shown.